# Validating a string inside of a string

Tags: ruby, api, automation, cucumber

I'm starting a cucumber automation and I'm struggling to validate a simple string,
cucumber is telling me the following:

```
expected: "[The value '123456789' is not valid.]"
 got: ["The value '123456789' is not valid."]
```

the code I wrote for that validation: `expect(@response['errors']['id']).to eql "[The value '123456789' is not valid.]"`

how can I make such validation? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Move your quotes inside the Array? `"[The value '123456789' is not valid.]" != ["The value '123456789' is not valid."]` but `["The value '123456789' is not valid."] == ["The value '123456789' is not valid."]`

Comment: Are you sure your actual value is a string, not an array of strings?

Comment: you were both right, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

AhmeDEV49's answer is already good, I just want to suggest using another matcher, [`include`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher) instead of `eql`, like this:

```
expect(@response['errors']['id']).to include "The value '123456789' is not valid."
```

Then you do not have to care about the array brackets at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a mistake in your assertion :

Just move double quote inside your array

```
eql "[The value '123456789' is not valid.]"
```

to

```
eql ["The value '123456789' is not valid."]
```

Answer (score 0):

The response was a array of strings, so the following worked:

```
expect(@response['errors']['id']).to eql ["The value '123456789' is not valid."]
```